# How to fetch nearest users post from many users post from cloud firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch nearest users.I have many users and i take user location using geolocator and store the latitude and longitude in cloud firestore.**So my question is from many users how can I find the neraby user.Here i cannot set certain radius because the nearest user may not be in that certain radius**.The distance may be 100km or 100 m between the users.Fluttergeofire wont work here as it deals with map.**For example I am a user, another nearest user of that app will be shown on my screen this is the main idea.No certain radius or distance will e set here.** User details are stored under a document and the document name is user id.How can i fetch the nearest user using flutter and cloud firestore

[image]

Comment: what did you try? How will you determine which user is the **nearest user** according to your database?

Comment: Does nearest user mean by location?

Comment: Yea nearest by location

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library for that, it's called Geo Flutter Fire.

With it, you can query for document within given range.

Link to package :- https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Geoflutterfire directly hadles with map. I want to fetch user details which are nearest by location